# Roles from reaction

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

So when bot sends a certain message, it reacts to it too. Now m tryin to check a user who reacted to that reaction has a certain role or not but so far I haven't been able to do so.

```js
 bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
            //var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id = user.id);
            //if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Bronze')) return(message.channel.send("you dont have role."));

if (reaction.message.members.roles.cache.has('729452091168260188')) return(message.channel.send("you have the role"));
            else { console.log("you dont have role"); }
         })
```

Comment: Please edit into the question the code you have so far.

Comment: Show what you tried and explain why it fails. "I haven't been able" is not a problem description.

Comment: i have edited it. I tried to do it this way , but it gives me error - "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined"

Comment: Then the problem is that reaction.message.members is undefined try printing reacrion.message.members and see if it equals anything

Comment: `//var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);` You have this code commented that's probably is what you need, remove the comment and change  `reaction.message.members.` to `member.` and `find` to `get` because you have the id no need to find it

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the following line of code:

```js
reaction.message.members.roles.cache.has('729452091168260188')
```

The [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object has no property `members`, it should be [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member):

```js
reaction.message.member.roles.cache.has('729452091168260188')
```